# Existe una solución para Notice: Undefined index: id in en un update?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sql, ajax

Sólo tengo una gran duda, como puedo hacer que mi `id` de mi línea no se vea afectado, por ejemplo: Donde me actualizo la cantidad de artículos que solo me funciona sí en mi cláusula `WHERE` pongo `'1'`, pero si pongo una variable `$id`, no me deja, me envía el error de que mi variable no esta definida.

```js
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input').on('blur', function() {
        var field = $(this);
        var validationField = field.parent().find('.validation');
        var dataString = 'value='+field.val()+'&field='+field.attr('name');
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "../logica/process.php",
            data: dataString,
            success: function(data) {
        field.val(data);
                validationField.hide().empty();
 
                setTimeout(function() {
                    validationField.append('<i class="fa fa-check"></i>');
                validationField.show();
                }, 500); 
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

```html
 <div class="card card-frame">
  <div class="card-body">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="id" id="id" value="<?=$row['id']?>" maxlength="32">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nombre" id="nombre" value="<?=$row['nombre']?>" maxlength="32">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="pedido" id="pedido" value="<?=$row['pedido']?>" maxlength="75">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="status" id="status" value="<?=$row['status']?>" maxlength="75">
  
  </div>
  </div>
```

```
<?php
 
include('../logica/configajax.php');

$data = $_POST['value'];
$field = $_POST['field'];
$id=$_POST['id'];

echo $update="UPDATE orden SET ".$field." = '".$data."' WHERE id=$id";
        
     $link->query($update);
echo $data;

?>
```

Comment: No estás pasando nada con la clave `id` en la variable `dataString`, por eso el Undefined Index. Agrega un `var_dump($_POST);` y dinos qué muestra.

Comment: en este caso, como puedo integrarlo? @A.Cedano

Comment: ¿Puedes decirnos qué muestra el `var_dump($_POST);`? En jQuery puedes usar `serialize()` para obtener los valores del form.

Comment: Puedes intentar algo así: `var mData: $('.card-body :input').serialize();` y luego pasar `mData` en el parámetro `data` de la petición Ajax, o sea, cambiar esto: `data: dataString,` por esto: **`data: mData,`**. Si no funciona, en cualquier caso depura los datos que estás recibiendo con `var_dump`  y dinos el resultado de esa depuración.

Comment: @A.Cedano cuando aplico este procedimiento que me comentas me sale esto: `array (size=4)
  'id' => string '1' (length=1)
  'nombre' => string 'user@blindfactory.mx' (length=20)
  'pedido' => string 'persianas' (length=9)
  'status' => string 'pendiente de confirmar' (length=22)
`

Comment: Pues ahí ya deberías recibir el valor del id, ¿cuál es el problema ahora?

Answer (score 0):

No estas enviando el campo `id`. Debes incluirlo en la variable `dataString`:

```
var id = $('#id').val();    
var dataString = 'id=' + id +'&value='+field.val() +'&field='+field.attr('name');
```

Esto funcionará solo estas trabajando con un registro por vista, si tienes varios necesitas hacer algunas modificaciones como agregar los nombre de los input como arreglos o nombres dinámicos, por lo que veo haces las modificaciones después de que el usuario sale del campo (onblur).

Comment: cuando integro esta linea de código me dice: **Uncaught TypeError: "#id".val is not a function**

Comment: Faltaba el `$`, ya edite la respuesta con los cambios.

Comment: excelente!! ya me edita la primera fila, alguna otra recomendación para poder editar las otras filas, me percate que si edito un input me lo actualiza del id=2 si quiero editar otro input del id=1 me sigue actualizando el id=2

Comment: solo me hace el **UPDATE** en el ultimo registro @MR DEV